# FontAwesome icons not vertically aligned using Foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation, font-awesome

FontAwesome: 4.7 (newest version)
Foundation 6.4.2 (newest version)

Whenever I put two or more FontAwesome icons next to each other horizontally, they are not vertically aligned. I've tried various vertical-align CSS styles and cannot get it to work. Please help!

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
<div class="row callout">
  <div class="small-2 columns">
    <a href="" title="move up"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-sort-asc"></i></a>
    <a href="" title="move down"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-sort-desc"></i></a>
 </div>
 <!-- another div with more columns here, totaling 12 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `a:{display: inline;}`

Comment: inline-block do you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but neither inline not inline-block on the <a> element changed anything. I tried them on both elements and each one individually. What about on the <i> elements?

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, this example has nothing really to do with Foundation, but everything to do with FontAwesome. The particular icons you've chosen happen to only take up part of the space of the font, and be placed at the top and bottom of the line. Full height icons line up just fine. You can see this illustrated in this code example (linked in this pen: https://codepen.io/kball/pen/mMNyrZ) where I add 2 full-height icons to the 2 half-height icons from your example.

```
<a href="" title="move up"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-sort-asc"></i></a>
<a href="" title="move down"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-sort-desc"></i></a>

<a href=""><i class="fa fa-2x fa-snowflake-o"></i></a>
<a href=""><i class="fa fa-2x fa-soccer-ball-o"></i></a>
```